# Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have a Flash app made up of AS3 components that I am trying to run in Flex.

In Flash, after the main component is added to the stage, the loader object (loaderInfo.loader) is null which is fine and I handle that.

In Flex, on the applicationComplete event I add the the main component to the stage and the loader object's getter throws an exception - Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information.

Also, the INIT event, which is dispatched when the properties and methods of a loaded SWF file are accessible, is not firing which is probably part of the problem. But I can't figure out why it is not being dispatched.

Any ideas why the same code has two different results?

Comment: Please amend this and show some of the code.  Your explanation is very hard to understand, and also I want to see more about the function that is fired in your applicationComplete event listener method.  If you provide more of your code, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, that seems like a frustrating problem. When you say "main component", I presume you mean the document class in Flash?

I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable about flex to comment on the problem you described, but I can suggest that you try using `ADDED_TO_STAGE` instead of `INIT` as your event...

```
public class MainFlashClass extends Sprite {
  public function MainFlashClass() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onInit);
  }
  public function onInit(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onInit);

    // do your initialisation code here
  }
}
```

This might work for both scenarios. I've found `ADDED_TO_STAGE` to be more helpful because it always gets fired, whether the class is already loaded when the swf is executed (like the document class), or if it's being loaded with a `Loader`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what's going on with INIT event, but I do know that in flash player 9, which I'm assuming is the version of your SWF? There's a bug with referencing the loader through its own evt target. Basically if you are loading something and you try and access properties of the loader though evt.target.loaderInfo.loader it never can find itself and throws the error you described in your question. I believe it's a known bug for flash player 9 that was fixed with the release of CS4 and flash player 10.

Here's a link to a thread describing some of the problem, hopefully it helps

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=137599

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to post code so we an see better.

With that said, after addChild are you attempting to grab the loaderInfo for the "main component" or for your mx:Application?

Pseudo

```
//onApplicationComplete event handler
var myswf:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
myswf.load(...);
addChild(nmyswf);

trace(myswf.loaderInfo.loader);
//end onApplicationComplete
```

Is that what you're doing? If so, you need to add an event listener to your "main component" (assuming an externally loaded swf) to find out when Event.COMPLETE happens.

```
var myswf:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
myswf.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMySWFComplete);
//..rest of code
```

Hope that helps. If not, post code.